# Response header is not getting displayed in swagger UI rendered in Google chrome

Tags: java, jersey, swagger, swagger-ui

I am populating and returning javax.ws.rs.core.Response to Swagger UI in the following way-

```
 return Response.status(503)
 .entity(new SomeErrorEntity())
 .header("SOME_HEADER","SOME_HEADER").build();
```

Here the json for SomeErrorEntity object getting displayed in Response body properly but the header "SOME_HEADER" is not getting displayed under Response header in swagger UI rendered in Google chrome.Only "content-type": "application/json" is displayed under header. But interestingly "SOME_HEADER" header is displayed in IE 11 but not in other browsers (latest chrome, Mozilla).
Here I am using version 1.3.13 of swagger-jaxrs_2.10, version 1.3.13 of swagger-core_2.10, version 1.5.3-M1 of swagger-annotations and version 1.3.13 of swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10. Also I am using following CORS configuration in web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Did some initial investigation and found that there is some problem with rendering header in the Swagger UI and fixes suggested does not apply in my case as I am not using any swagger.js explicitly. So, little puzzled on how to find a solution to this problem. Hence, any suggestion to fix this issue will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you have to send this `Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-Total-Results` to client because of CORS issuse

Comment: But how can I send this to client. Does Response has any method or any other property to set this Access-Control-Expose-Headers:X-Total-Results. Can you help me with any pseudo code which suits my present implementation for sending back this property to client side.